# Java expression editor

Tags: java, regex, editor

I am looking for a tool where I can write and evaluate expression, statement in Java. say, Math.exp(5), 3<<5 and so on. Can you please let me know about any tool?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @bcsb1001 actually i need a tool where i can test my logic likewise in Debug mode. say i need to know what is Math.exp(8) then i have to write small test prog...its really irritating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php 
 or the one which supports many programming languages http://ideone.com/

Comment: @sol4me...its really "solution4me" thanks for giving me such a wonder full link this is what i am looking for :)